# Using the general definition to compute the divergence: what is wrong?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, divergence-operator

My main reference is John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds. The divergence is defined as:

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. If $X$ is a tangent vector field and $dV$ is its volume form, then the **divergence** is
>   $$div X=d(X\lrcorner\ dV)/dV$$
>   where $X\lrcorner\ dV$ denotes the **interior multiplication**.

I am trying to compute the divergence of a vector field $X=A\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}+B\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}+C\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}$ in the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$, where one has $dV=dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3$.

By definition,
$$dV=dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3\\
=\frac{1}{6}(dx^1\otimes dx^2\otimes dx^3-dx^1\otimes dx^3\otimes dx^2\\
+dx^2\otimes dx^3\otimes dx^1-dx^2\otimes dx^1\otimes dx^3\\
+dx^3\otimes dx^1\otimes dx^2-dx^3\otimes dx^2\otimes dx^1)$$
Then
$$X\lrcorner\ dV=\frac{1}{6}(Adx^2\otimes dx^3-Adx^3\otimes dx^2\\
+Bdx^3\otimes dx^1-Bdx^1\otimes dx^3\\
+Cdx^1\otimes dx^2-Cdx^2\otimes dx^1)\\
=\frac{1}{3}(Adx^2\wedge dx^3+Bdx^3\wedge dx^1+Cdx^1\wedge dx^2)$$
and
$$d(X\lrcorner\ dV)=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial B}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial C}{\partial x^3})dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3$$
By the definition above, the divergence would be $\frac{1}{3}(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial B}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial C}{\partial x^3})$. Why is there an extra coefficient?

---

**Update:** In response to one of the comments: how I computed the interior product.

**Note that here $M=\mathbb R^3$ and $TM,T^*M\cong\mathbb R^3$ denote the tangent/cotangent spaces with their subscripts omitted rather than the bundles.**

First, $dx^1\otimes dx^2\otimes dx^3\in T^*M\otimes T^*M\otimes T^*M\cong L(TM,TM,TM;\mathbb R)$. The isomorphism (to the space of multilinear mappings) is given by
$$(dx^1\otimes dx^2\otimes dx^3)(u,v,w)=(dx^1(u))\cdot(dx^2(v))\cdot(dx^3(w))\text{ for }u,v,w\in TM$$
Hence if $X$ is as above we have
$$X\lrcorner(dx^1\otimes dx^2\otimes dx^3)(v,w)=dx^1(X)\cdot(dx^2(v))\cdot(dx^3(w))\\=A\cdot(dx^2(v))\cdot(dx^3(w))=Adx^2\otimes dx^3$$
Then by linearity I obtain the expression for $X\lrcorner dV$.

Comment: I don't think you've computed the interior product right. See the antiderivation property which defines it linearly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product

Comment: @ElliotG I did use the same definition. See my edited question. But I still don't see where the problem is.

Comment: You are not following Lee's convention for defining the wedge product; see Equation (14.3) in his book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" (I assume he uses the same convention in the book you cite).  With his convention, there is no factor of 1/6 in the formula for dV as you expand it out, and $dx\wedge dy = dx\otimes dy - dy\otimes dx$.

Comment: @JeffreyCase Thank you! I was only using Lee's book as a manual and didn't know that he uses this convention. But wouldn't different conventions lead to different definitions of things related to differential forms, say divergence, Laplace-Beltrami operators, etc.? For example, how should I define the interior multilpication now for the computation in my question to be correct, if I do adopt the convention that $1/6$ stays?

Comment: Different conventions will lead to different definitions, but they all agree up to some constant multiple.  The choice of conventions is usually made so that certain formulas "look nice".  Lee has a good discussion of what this means for the interior and exterior products on forms, as well as the exterior derivative, in Chapter 14 of "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".  Basically, you want your products to be derivations on the space of differential forms, and but your definition does not have that property.